# How can I merge into parts from this CAD model I imported?

Tags: particles, bones, import

I imported a STL CAD file, and what I want to do is form a small number (in the 10s) of discrete parts, so that I can attach bones and animate. I am new to Blender aside from a few tutorials so please excuse :) I am trying to animate a robot from a CAD file.

See image below. I want to join these faces/edges/whatevers together and call it the "base" part and then add a bone that will eventually be able to rotate the parts above it in the Z.
[image]

How should I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: You talk about "merging" and "joining" but it sounds like what you want to do is separate

Comment: Oh man I'm so confused on terminology... I just want to make it into a single part. What would separating do to this end?

Comment: From what I read I assumed you wanted to make that selected part in your image a separate object, loose and independent from the rest of the arm, did I understand correctly? If so that specifically makes it separating, not joining. Anyway you can try it yourself, just select a bunch of faces in edit mode then press `P`> *Separate Selection* that makes a new object from selection

Comment: Dude... I think that did it. Thank you so much, please feel free to leave an answer which I will accept

Comment: No need, just please accept the marked question as duplicate instead, if you feel it answers your question, so this can be safely closed as duplicate

Comment: I guess it's the same answer, but honestly I think the question is phrased differently enough to be useful to others. For example, that question already understands the concept of separating, meanwhile with mine I have to learn this concept even exists :)