# Separating faces of a mesh to submesh

Tags: mesh

I am importing a mesh into blender to modify some parts before I use it with babylonjs.
What I am trying to achieve is to move all of the triangles from the selected (shown in the image below) to a seperate sub-mesh for each of the triangle.

[image]

The reason i want to do this is because using babylonjs I need to visualise a color change where if color is selected for a square, all of the others around it will have the same color base that fades out more the further the square is.

Comment: What is a sub-mesh? Blender has no concept of sub-meshes. You also don't need to separate meshes to apply different materials. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: It's basically a mesh inside a mesh @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: There is no such thing in Blender. You can detach those faces from the surrounding ones inside the same object, but not as a "mesh inside a mesh" it is just a separate chunk. But you don't really need to do that to assign a different material has explained in the link above.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, however the problem is that the I need to assign around 40 different materials @DuarteFarrajotaRamos.

Comment: That makes no difference, you can assing as many materials as desired. Anyway see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84166/how-can-i-merge-into-parts-from-this-cad-model-i-imported you can separate into a new object with `P` > *Separate > Selection*